# Constructing command from array elements and checking exit code with if in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

Here is a minimal example:

```
#!/bin/bash

testFunc() (
    shopt -s extglob
    local posArgs=();
    for((i=1; i<="$#"; ++i))
    do
        posArgs+=("${!i}");
    done
    #<uncomment to see> echo "${posArgs[@]:0:$((${#posArgs[@]} - 1))}";
    if ${posArgs[@]:0:$((${#posArgs[@]} - 1))};
    then 
        return 0;
    fi
    return 1;
)
```

- Function body uses `()` instead of `{}` to limit the scope of shopt
- Function discards the last argument and executes the rest and checks exit code, if 0 returns 0, else returns 1. Quotes and command substitution are not used on purpose.

Here is what works:

```bash
testFunc "echo" "whatever" "discardThis"; #whatever
testFunc "pidof" "memcached" "discardThis"; #12435
testFunc "pwd" "discardThis"; #path/to/pwd
testFunc "pwd" "discardThis"; #path/to/pwd
testFunc "/bin/bash" "-c" "pwd" "discardThis"; #path/to/pwd
testFunc "/bin/bash" "-c" "pwd;pwd" "discardThis"; #path/to/pwd\npath/to/pwd NOTE:no space between ; and pwd
```

Here is what does not work:

```bash
testFunc "/bin/bash" "-c" "[[ 2 -eq 2 ]]" "discardThis"; #error
testFunc "/bin/bash" "-c" "\"[[ 2 -eq 2 ]]\"" "discardThis"; #error
testFunc "/bin/bash" "-c" "\"echo helloo\"" "discardThis"; #error
testFunc "/bin/bash" "-c" "echo helloo" "discardThis"; #exits with 0 but logs nothing
testFunc "/bin/bash" "-c" "pwd; pwd" "discardThis"; #logs pwd ONCE
testFunc "/bin/bash" "-c" "\"pwd; pwd\"" "discardThis"; #error
```

Above logs error like: `helloo": -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching...`
Interestingly to make the above work, you can pass `eval`:

```bash
testFunc "eval" "/bin/bash" "-c" "\"echo helloo\"" "discardThis"; #helloo
testFunc "eval" "/bin/bash" "-c" "\"[[ 2 -eq 2 ]]\"" "discardThis"; #exits with 0
testFunc "eval" "/bin/bash" "-c" "pwd; echo haha; pwd;" "discardThis"; #path/to/pwd\nhaha\npath/to/pwd
testFunc "eval" "/bin/bash" "-c" "pwd; pwd" "discardThis"; #Correctly logs pwd TWICE
```

Seems like when there is a command like `echo` that expects an argument, or some other complex command `eval` is needed. How can I avoid this? How can I make them work without eval.

I am not interested in implementing what I want, I am interested in why `bin/bash` fails to parse a string like `echo hi`.

Comment: Have you tried running under `set -x`?

Comment: `why bin/bash fails to parse a string like echo hi.` You haven't posted example of it. Could you post an example of the question you are asking? `Quotes and command substitution are not used on purpose` Do you understand the implications of not using quotes?

Comment: @choroba good catch, echo seemed to output `/bin/bash -c "pwd; pwd"` but set -x revealed it went under splitting: `/bin/bash -c '"pwd;' 'pwd"'`

Comment: Note that `if cmd; then return 0; else return 1; fi` can usually be re-written as simply `cmd` (if it is the last command in the function) or `cmd; return $?` if it is not.  (The only difference is that the `if/else` guarantees a return value of only 0 or 1 and disallows other non-zero results, converting them all to 1.)

Comment: If the return status has to be 1, then `$cmd || return 1`

Comment: Use `local posArgs=("$@")` and you don't need the for-loop.

Comment: The `${var:offset:length}` uses an _arithmetic context_ for "offset" and "length", so the arithmetic `$((...))` is not needed ==> `${posArgs[@]:0:$# - 1}`. Or, you could just do `local posArgs=("${@:1:$# - 1}")` to take the first N-1 args

Comment: `declare -p posArgs` is a very handy way to inspect a variable, much better then `echo` IMO

Comment: @glennjackman many thanks for the comments. Indeed, `$((...` was not needed, as with the for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why bin/bash fails to parse a string like echo hi.

If you interested why the following (which was **not** in your examples):

```
testFunc "/bin/bash" "-c" "echo hi" "discardThis"
```

outputs nothing, then let's dive in:

```
${posArgs[@]:0:$((${#posArgs[@]} - 1))
```

The result of **unquoted** expansion undergoes *word splitting* (and filename expansion!! Lucky you, you didn't test with `*`). Word splitting splits the stuff on spaces (and tabs and newlines, with default IFS), no matter what you input. The 3 words argument:

```
"/bin/bash" "-c" "echo hi"
```

become 4 words, `echo hi` is split on spaces:

```
/bin/bash -c echo hi
```

Or more visible, so that you can see:

```
/bin/bash -c 'echo' hi
```

From `man bash`:

```
-c       [...] If there  are  arguments  after  the command_string, the first argument is assigned to $0 [...]
```

`hi` is assigned to `$0` for `bash`, and then bash executes `echo` with no arguments.

> How can I avoid this?

Use quotes.

> How can I make them work without eval.

Use quotes.

Check your script with shellcheck.

Comment: I really thought I could dodge quoting with this particular example. `set -x` showed it was not possible. Correct answert, great catch. Thanks.